# List of constants

Tags: interface

In the Blender UI, in every numeric input field, I can enter simple expressions, e.g. `2+4`. I just found out that even `pi` and `e` are supported values which are then converted to `3.14` and `2.71`, respectively.

I was not able to find a list of supported constants or functions. What can I enter there?

Just for clarification, I don't want Python scripting, Math nodes or something else, just these input fields:

[image: Input field accepting pi]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of all possible math expressions. 
Everything behind the python "math." is a valid input:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html

Comment: Although listed, `tau` is not considered valid input

Comment: You're right. That's interesting. I can't explain why that is... As all expressions are evaluated by Python, I thought they all would be available inside of Blender.